# Intermittent slow perf on Redis : Where to start?

Tags: redis

If simple read/write calls to Redis sometimes take 3-6 seconds instead of the usual sub-millisecond, where do I start looking?

Redis server CPU never goes over %2. And I am pretty sure networking is no issue.

We have a pretty basic setup.

Using Redis 2.6.7 on a CentOS 2.6 kernel.

Comment: You're not out of memory, are you? What persistence model are you using?

Comment: @JonatanHedborg  The memory consumption reported by redis info is low (50-60mb total).  Using the stock persistence config.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by reviewing the points described on this page:

[Redis latency problems troubleshooting](http://redis.io/topics/latency)

Since your CPU consumption is low, I would first check memory and disk I/O issues:

- what is the current memory consumption? (free, redis info command)
- is the box swapping? (vmstat, top)
- which persistence mechanism is used? (rdb or aof)
- how much I/O activity cqn you measure when the problem occurs (iostat)
- do you run your stuff on top of a Xen VM? (fork latency issue)

Comment: Thanks! I will be back on this project in about two weeks and will check. This box does run on vmware esx.